# Converting a string into a CheckBox

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, flex4

I have a string which is ultimately the id of a CheckBox.

What I need to be able to do is to access the CheckBox's properties from the string

var myCheckBox:Object;
var myString:String;

myString = "checkbox_1"

myCheckBox = Object(myString); ?!?!

... and then I'd need to get to myCheckBox.selected, and myCheckBox.label etc

Answer (score 3):

easier answer:

```
if(this.hasOwnProperty(myString) && this[myString] is CheckBox) {
    myCheckBox = this[myString] as CheckBox
}
```

It's a bit of overcoding (since the as keyword will return a null if it's not a checkbox and you could better handle it that way with potentially less code), but that should do ya.
Best of luck.

Comment: Doesn't need "this.hasOwnProperty()", as "this[myString]" will just return undefined if it's not available, but this is the right answer :)

Comment: +1. You can also check `if(myString in this && this[myString] is CheckBox)`

Answer (score 0):

If you know what `DisplayObjectContainer` (e.g. `Sprite`, `MovieClip`) the `CheckBox` is inside you can use [getChildByName](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName).

Unfortunately if you are using Flex containers (like `Group`) there is no function `getElementByName()`. There is [getElementAt](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/components/supportClasses/GroupBase.html#getElementAt) so you could write a loop that iterates over all of a `Groups` elements until it encounters one that matches the name you have.